# Static layout vs. jQuery wrapInner - different output

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I write code like this one:

```
<body>
    <xmp>
        <p>hello world</p>
        <div></div>
    </xmp>
</body>
```

The output will be:

> ```
> <p>hello world</p>
> <div></div>
> ```

However, the code

```
<body>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <div></div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$( "body" ).wrapInner( "<xmp />" );</script>
```

Will not give me the tags. The output will be just:

> ```
> hello world
> ```

Why this happens and how it may be fixed?

Comment: [`<xmp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp). **Obsolete**. This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Simply saying, I want to see the tags in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: you should not use `<xmp>`**

It doesn't work because you are using DOM methods, which only move DOM nodes around. The contents of the body are still elements. The xmp element just provides a custom HTML parsing algorithm. So you need to reparse all the source. This will destroy all the internal data of your elements.

```js
var xmp = document.createElement('xmp');
xmp.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML; // Custom XMP parsing
document.body.innerHTML = ''; // Remove current contents
document.body.appendChild(xmp); // Insert XMP
```

```html
<p>hello world</p>
<div></div>
```

But relying on XMP's magic is wrong. The proper way to parse as text is using `textContent`.

```js
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
var code = pre.appendChild(document.createElement('code'));
code.textContent = document.body.innerHTML; // Parse as text
document.body.innerHTML = ''; // Remove current contents
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

```html
<p>hello world</p>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, the second (i.e. without xmp) way works for the code provided in my question. However, if I have `foo <table> foo` inside body, the output will be still incorrect. https://jsfiddle.net/03r1jqmm/ . The `<table>` tag is somehow below the `foo foo` line.

Comment: @johnc.j. Yes, because that's incorrect markup, which has already been parsed as HTML. If you want the original source, you will need an AJAX request.